How to suppress c# compiler warning in a razor file?
if I suppress it like that in the razor file
@{ #pragma warning disable CS0618 }
@inject SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager
@{ #pragma warning restore CS0618 }

Visual Studio is satisfied with that code, but dotnet compile still throws CS0618 warning.
Also it does not seem to be possible in include @inject into @{ ... } construct

It would be better to not use an obsolete class wouldn't it?

You could always move that code to a .cs file if you have to use it

there is some issue with the new one, the only known and workable workaround is to use the old class. Unfortunately it's not always better not to use obsolete class

In a code-behind file (MyComponent.razor.cs) it would become
#pragma warning disable CS0618 
[Inject] public SignOutSessionStateManager SignOutManager { get; set; }
#pragma warning restore CS0618

